# Getting error when trying to run Python in vscode

Tags: json, macos, visual-studio-code, mkdir

this is my first time using vscode. I am currently using a Macbook Pro with version 10.15.2 of macOS Catalina. Every time I try to debug, I get this "Unable to create 'launch.json' file inside the '.vscode' folder (Unable to write file '/Users/.vscode/launch.json' (NoPermissions (FileSystemError): Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/Users/.vscode'))." I have no idea what I need to do to fix this and need help because I need to work on a class project. Please explain in detail as I will most likely not understand yet. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

try to manually create a .vscode directory inside your project and make shure the user youre on has sufficent permissions to create and write to files in that directory

Comment: Okay so how do I do that?

Comment: try just creating a folder named .vscode then try running the code i assume youre using your own home computer and are logged as administer so the permissions should be fine